# Assembly x86, what is the address of each array? (checking my answer)

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

```
SECTION .DATA
V1 DB "ABC",0AH,0BH,10,11,-1,-2
V2 TIMES 2 DD 0X124F77AB
V3 DW 5,0XFE,-12,32,-1,100
```

Assuming the address start from 1000H, what is the base address for each variable?

My attempt:

- V1 = 1000H
- V2= 1016H (+8 byte)
- V3 = 1032H (+8 byte)

and whatever after V3 it's going to be 1056H(+16 byte)?

Comment: How come you assume `V1 will only hold one byte?

Comment: Look at V1 again.

Comment: @usr2564301 my mistake i meant the size of V1 is 8 bytes, i mistaken for 8 bits

Comment: @prl is it correct now?

Comment: No, I think you need to count more carefully (both V1 and V3). 1008h + 8 is not 1016h. 1008h + 8 is 1010h. 1016h + 16h is 102ch. 1016h + 16 is 1026h. (I’m not sure which you meant, but it’s wrong either way.)

Comment: @prl isn't 1 byte= 8 bits= so 02H?

Comment: Are you thinking 1 byte = 2 halves?  That's not what H means.  It's a base, not a unit. 
"h" means the number is in hex, not decimal.  Also, I count 9 total bytes for the first `db` directive / pseudo-instruction.  Assemble it with an assembler and check the listing (like with `nasm foo.asm  -l foo.lst` (or `-l /dev/stdout` to output to the terminal) since this appears to be NASM syntax.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SECTION .DATA vstart=1000h
V1 DB "ABC",0AH,0BH,10,11,-1,-2
V2 TIMES 2 DD 0X124F77AB
V3 DW 5,0XFE,-12,32,-1,100
```

The V1 label points to a DB (Define Bytes) instruction. The instruction is given data as follows: 1. A string of 3 letters, 2. two hexadecimal numbers, 3. two positive decimal numbers, and 4. two negative decimal numbers.

DB with a string allocates as many bytes as are in the string. (Whether these bytes represent letters, ASCII, or UTF-8 encoded codepoints doesn't matter to the assembler, it only sees bytes.) That's 3 bytes here.

DB with a number allocates a single byte for this number. It doesn't matter what base the numbers are specified in. The numbers are more specifically numeric expressions, that is they can have multiple terms joined by operators. This is 6 bytes here.

The entire DB instruction allocates 3 + 6 = 9 bytes.

The V2 label points to a TIMES instruction followed by a DD (Define Doublewords) instruction. TIMES inserts the following instruction as many times as specified in the number (numeric expression) given to it. This is 2 here. Each repetition is one DD with a single number, given in hexadecimal again. DD with a number allocates a doubleword. "Word" here refers to the 8086-based architecture, so a "word" is 16 bits. That is the same length as 2 bytes. So a "doubleword" is 32 bits, the same length as 4 bytes. Therefore the TIMES and DD instructions take up 2 times 4 bytes, 8 bytes.

The V3 label points to a DW (Define Words) instruction. As well here the "word" refers to the 16-bit operands of the 8086. So each number takes up 2 bytes. As there are 6 numbers, each taking up a word results in 12 bytes.

That means with a virtual start (vstart) of 1000h, V1 is at 1000h, V2 is at 1000h + 9, V3 is at 1000h + 9 + 8, and after the V3 line the next address will be 1000h + 9 + 8 + 12.

Now the only hurdle left is to convert the address expressions to numbers each. You will have to understand hexadecimal numerical representation to properly sum and list the addresses in this format. This results in 1009h for V2, 1011h for V3, and 101Dh for the next address.

Comment: One more extra question if you may? what can I conclude is inside EAX if for as example MOV EAX, [V2+1]?

Comment: `About to Execute : ldebug` \ `-a 200` \ `18DF:0200 dd 124F77AB, 124F77AB` \ `18DF:0208 ` \ `-a 100` \ `18DF:0100 mov eax, [200 + 1]` \ `18DF:0104 nop` \ `18DF:0105 ` \ `-rx` \ `386 registers are displayed` \ `-t` \ `EAX=AB124F77 EBX=00000000 ECX=00000000 EDX=00000000 ESP=0000FFFE EBP=00000000` \ `ESI=00000000 EDI=00000000 NV UP EI PL ZR NA PE NC` \ `DS=18DF ES=18DF SS=18DF CS=18DF FS=0000 GS=0000 EIP=00000104` \ `18DF:0104 90                nop` \ `-h eax` \ `AB124F77 (-54EDB089)  decimal: 2870103927 (-1424863369)` \ `-`

Comment: that's little bit confusing can you summarize ?

Comment: The doubleword 124F_77ABh is stored in little endian as the byte sequence ABh, 77h, 4Fh, 12h. Double that and it is ABh, 77h, 4Fh, 12h, ABh, 77h, 4Fh, 12h. Add offset 1 and we get the four bytes 77h, 4Fh, 12h, ABh. Again read as little endian this doubleword has the value AB12_4F77h.

Comment: When we added that offset 1, doesn't it mean we move the address 1 byte up?

Comment: also why did you consider 0X124F77AB is 124F77ABH in hex? its actually floating point number which converts to 6.5465185111..

Comment: A General Purpose Register like `eax` holds integer values not floating point numbers. 0x1234 and 1234h are the exact same number, "1234 in hexadecimal". The choice of 0x prefix or h suffix doesn't change the number. Please learn hexadecimal. Adding 1 to the offset addresses the doubleword that starts at byte address V2 + 1 = 100Ah. Read up on little endian.